# measure virtual machine live migration parameters in kvm/qemu

Tags: parameters, migration, virtual-machine, virtualization, kvm

I am using kvm/qemu for vm live migration. how can i understand downtime, total migration time and data exchanged after migration? is there any tools for measuring them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been meausring the performance of openstack server migrate using wireshark. You can ping the openstack instance from your control node, and have wireshark capture the icmp packets sent to the instance. CArry out live migration while pinging it. Take note of the time for which the packets are not captured by wireshark, and there you have it, an approximate measurement of performance of openstack server migrate.